# How to refactor these multiple else -if blocks?? Is there a better way to do

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-7

This code block checks if the item or the person is present in a particular group and gives authorization to view to only those members present.There are four such groups and multiple scenarios or probabilities.This feels like a code smell and would like to know a better way to do.fyi:item1, item2, item3, item4 are the keys for the groups

```
if ((in_array('item1', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                (in_array('item2', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                (in_array('item3', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item4', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))) {


            }
            elseif ((in_array('item2', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item3', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id))))) &&
                ((in_array('item4', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))){

            }

            elseif ((in_array('item1', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item3', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id))))) &&
                ((in_array('item4', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))){

            }

            elseif ((in_array('item1', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item2', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id))))) &&
                ((in_array('item4', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))){

            }

            elseif ((in_array('item3', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item2', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id))))) &&
                ((in_array('item4', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))){

            }


            elseif ((in_array('item3', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item2', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id))))) &&
                ((in_array('item1', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))){

            }


            elseif ((in_array('item2', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item3', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))) {

            }

            elseif ((in_array('item3', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item1', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))) {


            }

            elseif ((in_array('item1', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item2', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))) {

            }


            elseif ((in_array('item1', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item4', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))) {

            }

            elseif ((in_array('item4', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item2', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))) {

            }

            elseif ((in_array('item4', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))) &&
                ((in_array('item3', (Authorization::getAdmin($Id)))))) {

            }

           elseif(in_array('item1',(Authorization::getAdmin($Id))))
           {

           }

            elseif(in_array('item2',(Authorization::getAdmin($Id))))
            {

            }

            elseif(in_array('item3',(Authorization::getAdmin($Id))))
            {

            }

            elseif(in_array('item4',(Authorization::getAdmin($Id))))
            {

            }


        }
```

Comment: First: you only want to run `Authorization::getAdmin($Id)` once and store it in a variable.

Comment: What are you executing within your `if`/`elseif` blocks? If there is no pattern, it will be harder to simplify than if there is one.

Comment: Create 4 variables with the result of `in_array(...)` as this the current version calls it so many times.

Comment: @Namoshek in each else-if block I get the data from the table depending up on the condition and return the data to the view.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a query? Best is you give us one where 3 items have to match.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you could reduce it to this:

```
$groups = Authorization::getAdmin($Id);

foreach (['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'] as $group_key) {
    if (in_array($group_key, $groups)) {
        // give authorization to view that group
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely put the static function call result into a local variable. That'll save you a lot of processing power and reduce code.

I like [Don't Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2734189/dont-panic)'s solution and would expand on it to cross-index it with your permission matrix...

```
$permissions = ['I can do this' => ['item1'], 'I can do that' => ['item1', 'item2'], ... ];
$groups = Authorization::getAdmin($Id);
$authorization = [];

foreach (['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'] as $group_key) {
  if (in_array($group_key, $groups)) {
    $authorization[] = $group_key;
  }
}
```

And a way to get the permission result is a quick array search.

```
$permission = array_search($authorization, $permissions );
```

This gets you a singular result only; if it's more complex than that, you may have to build a complex statement to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks for the response.the scenario is such that I had to check all the possibilities and might not still be possible to avoid nested_else if statements.Is there any other possibility? or can the statements be included in the controller or any other approach??

Comment: Try to describe or add in the complexity of the permissions. A permissions array that I have shown will work, provided all possible combinations have been covered.